# MPGS retrieve session unexpected parameters

Tags: api, postman

I tried to follow the online guideline to do the hosted session integration.

When testing Retrieve session api using postman, the error occurred.

{
"error": {
"cause": "INVALID_REQUEST",
"explanation": "Unexpected parameter 'merchantId'"
},
"result": "ERROR"
}

I did settle the correct parameter, merchantId and sessionId.

https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Session%3a%20Retrieve%20Session.html?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually include the text "merchantId". You have to provide a valid merchant ID. Click on the "URL Parameters" tab on the link you posted.

```
{merchantId}  Alphanumeric + additional characters COMPULSORY
              The unique identifier issued to you by your payment provider."
```

The same goes for "sessionId".